# Replace a Number Value with Icons

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

So in a React project I have a line:

```
<div className="star-rating fas fa-star">{data?.starRating}</div>
```

This returns a Number between 1-5, but how do I replace that Number with a number of Star Icons? For example, a 3 Returns 3 Stars, 4 Returns 4 Stars etc.

Currently the CSS for this:

```
.star-rating{
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: "\f005";
  font-size: 1.5em;
  color: #FFD700;
}
```

But all this does is make the Number Yellow and not replace it with any icon

Comment: I'm not use to react to properly make an answer but I think you should make a loop that adds 1-5 icon div(s) depending on `starRating`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`repeat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat):

```js
function App({ stars }) {
  return <p className="stars">{"★".repeat(stars) + "☆".repeat(5 - stars)}</p>
}

ReactDOM.render(<App stars={4} />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
.stars { color: yellow }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.0.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.0.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using react methods you can make it like this

```
<div className="star-rating fas fa-star">
  {data?.starRating.map(_ => (
    <YourStarComponent />
  ))}
</div>
```

Comment: <YourStarComponent />

Does this mean having the star Rating as its own component though? I wanna keep them where they are for now if possible

Comment: By `<YourStarComponent />` I mean anything that displaying your stars. It can be simple div with styles or whatever. That loop will render N components\divs and N is equal to number of stars that you need. So feel free to put there anything you want.